# Fixed Action Button no MaterializeCSS não funciona

Tags: javascript, css, html5, materialize

Simplesmente não funciona, o botão até aparece mas nenhum dos botões do tipo funcionam. Já tentei usando o materialize via CDN e local mas não houve mudança.
Acredito que não haja erro no código pois depois de muito tentar e não funcionar peguei o exemplo do próprio site e mesmo assim nada... segue código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TESTES</title>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <!-- MATERIAL ICONS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal">
      <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
        <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a própria documentação, faltou você importar o jQuery antes do JS do Materialize, desta forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Outra coisa: é sempre uma boa prática adicionar os scripts no final do body pois otimiza o tempo de exibição da página:

```
<body>
  ... conteudo
  <script src="script1.js"></script>
  <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Fonte: http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

Comment: Rapaz, como eu deixei passar isso hein? E olha que passei um bom tempo fazendo e desfazendo, procurando erros!
Valeu pela ajuda!